# How can I change the size of a VR game canvas (height and width) depending of their content?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, unity-ui

I'm making a VR game where I hava a unity canvas set up as Word space, I'm plannoing to add a  plane as background to provide better constrast and use the colliders to allow the user grab it and place it wherevet him wants.

I need to change the size (height and width) of the canvas depending of the content so the content should be always inside the canvas.

Is there any component to allow me change the size of the canvas/container depending on the content of the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, what you're looking for is the [`Content Size Fitter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html) component.

You can put it on your world space canvas and it should resize to its content as documented. Depending on your needs this will also involve adding a `Vertical Layout Group` component or similar.